# Error with xml HttpGet

Tags: java, android

I have an app that makes use of an xml obtained with a HttpGet. In the url of the xml request has a key that changes every hour, this key is obtained through another url.

Example: www.test.com/xml?hr=123456

The app tries to get the xml. If errors occur, get the key in another HttpGet and updates in the xml url.

In the emulator works perfectly, but not on the device. Already put a trace and the key is successfully updated. But the xml request error continues.

I tried to put "no cache" in HttpGet

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient (httpParams);
HttpGet get = new HttpGet (url);
get.addHeader ("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); / / HTTP/1.1
get.addHeader ("Expires", "Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

but it did not work, is there anything that can be done?

My Complete Activity:

```
public class ShowActivity extends AdModctivity implements
  bbbAndroidConstantes, OnItemClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener {
  private ProgressDialog dialog;
  private Retf p;
  private Handler handler = new Handler();
  private Exception ex;
  private CheckBox check;
  private ParametrosTO parTO;
  ParametrosDataBase parDB;
  String ref;
  String pId;
  String logR;
  String kId;
  String ldesc;
  TextView txtRef;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listaprevisoeslayout);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    parDB = new ParametrosDataBase(this);
    parTO = parDB.listParametros();

    pId = bundle.getString(VAR_P_ID);
    ref = bundle.getString(VAR_P_REF);
    logR = bundle.getString(VAR_LOGR);
    kId = bundle.getString(VAR_KID);
    ldesc = bundle.getString(VAR_LDESC);
    txtRef = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRef);
    check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkWidget);

    WidgetDataBase wDb = new WidgetDataBase(this);
    if (wDb.searchWidget(pId, kId) != null)
        check.setChecked(true);

    check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ShowActivity.this, "",
            "Wait...", true);

    if (!Utilities.chkStatus(ShowActivity.this))
        return;
    downloadInfo();
    fillAdMod();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

}

private void downloadInfo() {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean flag = false;
            try {
                p = Controller.getInstance().getRetf(parTO.getUrl(), pId, kId);
                if ((p.getInfoP() == null) || (p.getInfoP().size() == 0)) {
                    flag = true;
                    String newUrl = getNewUrl();
                    Utilities.updateUrl(ShowActivity.this, newUrl);
                    parTO = parDB.listParametros();
                    p = Controller.getInstance().getRetf(newUrl, pId, kId);
                }
                refreshScreen();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (!flag) {
                    try {
                        String newUrl = getNewUrl();
                        Utilities.updateUrl(ShowActivity.this, newUrl);
                        parTO = parDB.listParametros();
                        p = Controller.getInstance().getRetf(newUrl, pId, kId);
                        refreshScreen();
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        ex = e1;
                        refreshScreenException();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ex = e;
                    refreshScreenException();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

/**
 * Thread to close dialog and show information
 */
private void refreshScreen() {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog.dismiss();
            fillInfo();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Thread to close dialog and show exception
 */
private void refreshScreenException() {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog.dismiss();
            fillInfoExcecao();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Fill information on screen
 */
private void fillInfo() {

    if (p == null) {
        Toast.makeText(ShowActivity.this, MSG_SEM_Retf,
                MSG_TIME_MILIS).show();
        this.finish();
    }

    if ((p.getErro() != null) && (p.getErro().trim().length() > 0)) {
        Toast.makeText(ShowActivity.this, p.getErro(),
                MSG_TIME_MILIS).show();
        this.finish();
    }

    if ((p.getPonto() == null) || (p.getPonto().size() == 0)) {
        Toast.makeText(ShowActivity.this, MSG_SEM_Retf,
                MSG_TIME_MILIS).show();
        this.finish();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat spf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    long localTime = Long.parseLong(p.getLocalTime());
    txtRef.setText(txtRef.getText() + " "
            + spf.format(new Date(localTime)));

    RetfAdapter RetfAdapter = new RetfAdapter(this, p);
    ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lista.setAdapter(RetfAdapter);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

/**
 * Apresenta mensagem em caso de exceo
 */
private void fillInfoExcecao() {
    if (ex instanceof bbbException) {
        Toast.makeText(ShowActivity.this,
                ((bbbException) ex).getMessage(), MSG_TIME_MILIS).show();
        ShowActivity.this.finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(ShowActivity.this,
                getString(R.string.msg_erroSistema), MSG_TIME_MILIS).show();
        ShowActivity.this.finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean isChecked) {
    PBean PBean = new PBean(pId, logR,
            ref, kId, ldesc);

    WidgetDataBase wDb = new WidgetDataBase(this);
    if (isChecked)
        wDb.addWidget(PBean);
    else
        wDb.deleteWidget(PBean);
}

private String getNewUrl() throws Exception
{
    String newUrl = Utilities.getHttp(bbbAndroidConstantes.URL_HOST_HORARIOS);
    return newUrl;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you paste in a little bit bigger fragment of your code please? Especially the part with your request retry logic.